# When there is an error processing a file before_save, after validation, should I raise an exception or return false and add an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, error-handling, conventions

If I have, for example, an image that pass all the validations, like, size, dimensions, type, etc, but when I have to process it, for some unknown reason ImageMagick throws an error anyway... how should I handle that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Rails 4 and earlier the [Active Record Validations and Callbacks Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution):

> If any *before* callback method returns exactly `false` or raises an exception, the execution chain gets halted and a ROLLBACK is issued [...]

So you can either let the exception bubble up into ActiveRecord or you can trap it yourself, translate it to something that makes sense within the context of your application, and return `false`. You can register errors inside a `before_save` callback so something like this might make sense:

```
before_save :do_magick_things

private

def do_magick_things
    # ImageMagick stuff...
    true
rescue ImageMagickError, FatalImageMagickError => e
    errors.add(:base, 'Some sort of sensible version of e.message')
    false
end
```

If you can translate the ImageMagick errors into something that makes sense to the end user then trapping and translating the ImageMagick exception (as in `do_magick_things`) would probably make the most sense; converting the exception into an error message also allows the caller to use `save!` if they want exceptions or `save` if they don't.

Comment: So it's not "anti-pattern" to add an errors on `before_save`. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: @Zequez: I don't think it is an anti-pattern, just don't use your `before_save` for validation.

Comment: I know, but for some reason I feel like the errors object should be used just for validation errors.

Comment: A validation failure is an error but not the only type of error that the user will be interested in. Telling them that something went wrong that wasn't their fault is better than handing them a 500 page.

Comment: I must be crazy because this just does not work for me. Surely the validations are complete by the time `before_save` is called, thus you can't add to `errors` and have it fail validation?

Comment: @TimFletcher: I just tested this again and it (still) works for me. A `before_save` can return `false` to stop the saving process and then `model.save` will also return `false`. Also, `model.errors` isn't cleared after a successful validation, it is cleared *before* validations are attempted so any errors added by a `before_save` should still be there immediately after `model.save` returns `false`.

Comment: @muistooshort You're right. I think my issue is that calling `valid?` still returns true because the validations get run and the model technically is still valid. Adding to the errors hash doesn't make it fail validation so I'm struggling to get my create action to show the validation errors properly.

Comment: @TimFletcher: You don't want to call `valid?`, just check the return value from `model.save` and then look at `model.errors` immediately after `model.save` returns `false`. I don't think I've ever needed to call `valid?`, I just try to save and deal with the failure. Calling `valid?` will reset `model.errors` and then run the validations so the `before_save` callbacks won't matter.